# What could be the alternative of Format function in 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am confused we have sql server 2008 on server but I have coded in 2012 and used FORMAT function which is not working there. What is the replacement for 2008 ? Please help we have very less time to deploy.

```
SET @ComplaintAutoGenCode = (
    SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), @OrgName + '/yy/MM/' + CAST(@MaxComplaintID AS VARCHAR))
)
```

Comment: I tried many things but cannot be done

Comment: Hi there, just mention what output you want?

Comment: the one that is expected from above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6726)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @ComplaintAutoGenCode VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @OrgName VARCHAR(50) = 'MyOrg'
DECLARE @MaxComplaintID INT = 20


SET @ComplaintAutoGenCode = @OrgName + '/' + 
                            CONVERT(varchar(6), getdate(), 11) + 
                            CAST(@MaxComplaintID AS VARCHAR)

SELECT @ComplaintAutoGenCode
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6726/0)**:

```
|                |
|----------------|
| MyOrg/16/01/20 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you expecting..

```
   declare @ComplaintAutoGenCode varchar(100)
,@OrgName varchar(100) = 'xyz',@MaxComplaintID int = 12

SET @ComplaintAutoGenCode = (

    SELECT @OrgName+format(GETDATE(),  '/yy/MM/')+ CAST(@MaxComplaintID AS VARCHAR)
)
select @ComplaintAutoGenCode
```

Comment: Format only works in SQL Server 2012 or later, he's on SQL Server 2008!